# How to display timestamp by using table columns

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I am new to one of my project. Previous people saved date and time in two columns in the below format :

- For date : `2015-04-15` (date type)
- For time : `04:20 PM` (varchar)

Now I want to compare the above columns with present date and time.

I tried this below query but it's showing `NULL`.

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(
    STR_TO_DATE('evnt_endDate Event_EndTime', '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i%p')
) 
FROM events
```

Please could any one tell me how to compare?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `concat()`:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(concat(evnt_endDate, ' ', Event_EndTime
                                        ), '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i%p')
                     )
```

Comment: You need to switch `STR_TO_DATE` and `concat`, plus you have a syntax error at `' 'Event_EndTime`.

Answer (score 0):

`'evnt_endDate Event_EndTime'` is a string. You need to reference the fields/columns and concatenate their values like

```
CONCAT(`evnt_endDate`, ' ', `Event_EndTime`)
```

The resulting query would then be

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP( STR_TO_DATE( CONCAT(`evnt_endDate`, ' ', `Event_EndTime`), '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i%p') ) from events
```